# Drinfeld center as lax end

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory, enriched-category-theory, bicategories

The Bernstein center of a category and the Drinfeld center of a monoidal category are very similar notions: While the first one is defined as the natural endomorphisms of the identity functor on the respective category, the latter is the monoidal category of endo-pseudonatural transformations of the identity-2-functor on the delooping bicategory of the respective monoidal category, see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Drinfeld+center.

By an easy identity of ends, the Bernstein center can also be written as 
$$Z(\mathcal{C})=\operatorname{End}(\operatorname{id}_\mathcal{C}) \cong \int_{c \in \mathcal{C}}\operatorname{Hom}(c,c)$$
Which becomes the only adequate way to define it when in the context of enriched categories onver a complete symmetric monoidal category $\mathcal{V}$ (since otherwise the natural transformations form just a set, not an element of $\mathcal{V}$).

Is the analogue for the Drinfield center, usind a lax end, also valid (which seems probable, following the discussion of 2-coends in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.02503.pdf, but I am not comfortable about the whole laxes and pseudos etc.) and, more importantly, does it coincide with the definition for enriched monoidal categories introduced in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.01447.pdf? I am not really aquainted enough with  2-categories myself to figure it out, so I would be very greatful for suggestions or more educated opinions on this (I was also told that there is a theory of centers of $E_k$-monoidal $(\infty,1)$-categories developed in HA, maybe this could be helpful to view the discussion in a different light? I don't know much about it myself though). Greetings and thanks in advance,

Markus Zetto

Comment: This is very much research level and should probably head to MO-the population that knows enough to talk intelligently about both Drinfeld centers and lax ends is very small.

Comment: In fact, given that Loregian's references to some thesis work around 1980 in that section are practically the only occurrences of lax (co)ends in the whole literature, it's almost impossible for me to imagine that your problem isn't open, although it's also possible that it's easy.

Comment: You might be right there, I've requested a migration. I too hoped that it wouldn't be that hard too show if someone had some knowledge about enriched bicategories, but I wasn't aware that law (co-)ends were actually that sparcely used. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! I would say that the Drinfeld center is a pseudo-end. If the Drinfeld center is defined as you said, as ${\sf PsNat}(1,1)$, then it's enough to apply coend, Example 7.1.9, just replacing all occurrences of "lax" with "pseudo".

PS: Re lax co/ends: they behave differently, often strangely: see coend, 7.1.18 for an example.

Comment: @Fosco Thank you very much, that would indeed resolve the first difficulty. Figuring out if both definitions are the same in the enriched case turns out to be a lot of work though...